# SharePoint Foundation 2010 solution cannot be deployed to SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-feature, sharepointfoundation2010

I have made a site in SharePoint Foundation 2010. I used team site as a starting template. I have saved it as my own custom template.

Next, I have added that solution to SharePoint Server 2010. When I tried to create a new site in SharePoint Server 2010 based on it, I got an error that a feature is missing. Missing feature guid is e8389ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0. Looking at the solution's ONet file, it appears to be a 'ReportServer Feature'.

Now, my question is: Is it really possible that SharePoint Foundation 2010 may contain features that do not exist in SharePoint Server 2010? Isn't SharePoint Server supposed to be wider set of SharePoint Foundation?

Please help. Thanks.

Same topic here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/db59de6e-e13a-47e8-9fc7-5f1fe461be86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, an MVP has answered this topic on MSDN forum. You may find the link to the thread in the question above.

In short, any feature that exists in default SP Foundation instance must exist in SP Server as well. In my case, I have had installed Sql Reporting to the server machine running SP Foundation, which has subsequently added 'Reporting Server' feature. That's where all the commotion came from. Cheers everyone!

Comment: Mark it as Answer.It will help someone.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the reminder. I completely forgot to mark it.